# ODBC SQL Server Unicode Bug?

Tags: c++, sql-server, unicode, mfc, odbc

**Background:**

We have an application that uses the ODBC API to interact with Access and SQL Server (dynamically, depending on user's configuration).

I have discovered a bug which might be in the ODBC SQL driver, or may be a misconfiguration issue with the ODBC DSN we create, or may be a bug somehow in our code.

When a document is edited and saved, we query the database to see if this file has a corresponding record in the database - if so, we update the record with the updated data from the document; if not, we do an insert to create the necessary record for it.

We use the filename as the unique primary key on our table, and this works fine normally.
The bug is that if the filename contains characters outside of the current ANSI code page, then the select indicates no matches:

```
   SQL:  SELECT * FROM "My Designs" WHERE "PATHNAME" = '\\FILE-SERVER\Home Folders\User Files\狭すぎて丸め処理が出来ません!!.foo'   [# matches = 0]
```

However, when the insert is attempted, we get a unique key violation (of course) - since there already is a record with that filename.

```
Database error: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__My Desig__1B3D5B4BF643706B'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.My Designs'. The duplicate key value is (\\FILE-SERVER\Home Folders\User Files\狭すぎて丸め処理が出来ません!!.foo).
The statement has been terminated.
```

I've been over the code with a fine-tooth comb, and I can see nothing wrong. :(

The SQL statement that is being generated produces the correct Unicode output of the filename.  Our application is compiled for Unicode.  The column is `SQL_WVARCHAR` in ODBC speak.

I've tried adding `AutoTranslate=no` to the DSN configuration string, but that appears to have no effect.

I've tried logging the database connection from ODBC control panel.  Sadly, that interface produces an ANSI log file - so I cannot verify UNICODE / ANSI issues using that tool.

**Questions:**

- Is there a tool I can use to verify that these statements are being
  created / issued correctly by the ODBC driver to the SQL Server
  database?
- Is there a better way to use ODBC so that the driver doesn't get canoodled by a simple UNICODE string in a SELECT query vs. an INSERT request?
- Any other ideas for how to approach this problem (short of replacing our technology)

Comment: Did you try your command with SQL Server Management Studio?  That's the first thing you should do, to make sure you're not wasting time believing it's an ODBC issue.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - Using SQL SMS fails to work any better.  Indeed, that same query produces 0 results, but one that contains characters only in the current code page produces valid results.  Any ideas?

Comment: The goal is to see if SMS can work at all.  If SMS can't process the query successfully, you won't be able to get a program that makes ODBC calls to work correctly.  I am no SQL Server expert, but SMS is usually the gold standard to see if a query works or not.

Comment: This seems crazy.  I must be doing something wrong somewhere. :(  But SMS doesn't error on that query - it just indicates 0 records.  Which is a lie, and breaks my code which is trying to deduce if I need to issue an INSERT or an UPDATE. :(

Comment: I've convinced myself it is SQL Server 12.0 that is the problem.  I hope to find a solution, but it is not in our code.

Comment: You might want to look at the type of the column (can it hold unicode). Then there is the fact that SQL Server only used UCS-2 up until some version. Lastly newer SQL Servers can use UTF-16 but the table has to be configured properly. You might think it makes no sense right now but perhaps the data you inserted is being translated to something such that more than one insert string ends up as the same string in the DB. Select rows from you db using some other criteria and look at what the filenames really contain.

Comment: Does the following work on SQL Server Management Studio? [NOTE the `N` before the string] `SELECT * FROM "My Designs" WHERE "PATHNAME" = N'\\FILE-SERVER\Home Folders\User Files\狭すぎて丸め処理が出来ません!!.foo'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the select statement, make sure you enclose the where clause string with a N to tell SQL it's unicode:

```
..."PATHNAME" = N'\\FILE-SERVER\Home Folders\User Files\狭すぎて丸め処理が出来ません!!.foo'
```

Also, MFC converts the data to MCBS or UNICODE depending on your configuration. Make sure you use CStringT in recordset.

Comment: Thanks - trying to get this to work now.  The N'string' syntax fails on MS Access (I feel like I must be doing something wrong in ODBC that this sort of crud isn't being handled by the driver?)  I'll upvote / mark as answer if I can get this working :)